# How should I create global function base on this situation php?

Tags: php, html

I have a `if()` code will be so long, and some of them share some common html code. I think the better way is that call each html question base on the if condition. Look at my code, ex. if `$fruit='apple'`, I want to echo the html code question 1,3,5. How should I make the global function for the questions?

```
<?php
    if($fruit=='apple'){
     /*call question 1,3,5*/
    }else if($fruit=='banana'){
     /*call question 1,2,4*/
    }/*.........a lot of else if.....*/

   /*question
    1. <div>Is it good?</div>
       .............some multiple choice here
       <input type="text" value="submit"/>
    2. <div>where is it from?</div>
       .............some multiple choice here
       <input type="text" value="submit"/>
    3. <div>...........</div>
        .............some multiple choice here
       <input type="text" value="submit"/>
    4. <div>..........</div>
       .............some multiple choice here
       <input type="text" value="submit"/>
    */

?>
```

Comment: organize it into an array `$arr = ['apple' => [1,3,5], 'banana' => [1,2,4]]` ecc

Comment: As a side note, some people prefer [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) when there are a lot of `elseif`s

Comment: switch is better? faster?

Comment: @ 0x13a. if i make the array, How can i make the number 1,2,3,4 represent the question 1,2,3,4.

Comment: to make the numbers represent their questions, you use another array. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your code like this:

```
$fruit = "apple";

if (in_array($fruit, ["apple", "banana"])) {
    echo '<div>Is it good?</div>
       .............some multiple choice here
       <input type="text" value="submit"/>';
}
if (in_array($fruit, ["banana", "pineapple"])) {
    echo '<div>where is it from?</div>
       .............some multiple choice here
       <input type="text" value="submit"/>';
}
// etc...
```

There are of course other ways to do it. You could build a data structure giving you all the information you need, including the HTML, and then with a just a small loop to output the selected HTML:

```
$fruit = "apple";

$questions = array(
    "1" => array(
        "question" => "Is it good?",
        "answers" => ["Fantastic", "So-so", "Never again"]
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "question" => "Where is it from?",
        "answers" => ["South America", "Africa", "Australia"]
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "question" => "Which color does it have",
        "answers" => ["Yellow", "Red", "Orange"]
    ), //...etc
);
$questionsForFruits = array(
    "apple" => [1, 3],
    "banana" => [1, 2],
    "pineapple" => [2]
);

$fruit = "apple";

foreach($questionsForFruits[$fruit] as $questionNo) {
    $q = $questions[$questionNo];
    echo "<div>{$q['question']}</div>
          <select>";
    foreach($q['answers'] as $index =>$answer) {
        echo "<option value = '$index'>$answer</option>";
    }
    echo "</select><br>
          <input type='text' value='submit'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Organize the options into an array

```
$questions = [
         'q1' => '<div>Is it good?</div>
                 .............some multiple choice here
                 <input type="text" value="submit"/>',
         'q2' => '<div>where is it from?</div>
                 .............some multiple choice here
                 <input type="text" value="submit"/>',
       ];

$fruit_questions = [
         'apple'  => [1,3,5],
         'banana' => [1,2,4],
         'guava' => [17,21,4],
       ];
```

Then when you need to get questions, simply do:

```
$question_keys = $fruit_questions[$fruit];

$html_of_questions = ''; // This will hold the questions to echo
foreach($question_keys as $question_key){
    $html_of_questions .= $questions['q'.$question_key]
}

echo $html_of_questions;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code is very simple and good. Very smart!